# Personal ID generator

Tags: java

I need a personal ID generator for Bulgarian IDs and since our IDs are 10 digits long I can't do it with an `int` number and I need some suggestions. I tried with this code but it doesn't work. It also needs to be above 999999999 or below 9999999999.

```
static class ID {
    Random random = new Random();
    long perID = random.nextLong(999999999);
}
```

Comment: you can modify the way you generate random number to ```perID = 1000000000 + random.nextFloat()*(9000000000)```

Comment: I suppose you are willing to accept repeats?

Answer (score 0):

```
Random random = new Random();
long perID = (long) (random.nextDouble() * 1000000000) + 999999999L;
```